# Laravel Page is not hitting the url

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to open a page in laravel with '/', but the page is refreshing infinitely and not showing anything,

Route Part:

```
Route::get("/", "HomeController@index")->name("home"); //Landing Page
```

Controller Part:

```
public function index(){
        return 1;
    }
```

[image]

> as the picture is showing its reloading every time and not opening
> anything

plz help me solving this

any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/` doesn't refer to your `public/` folder. So remove that part from your url

Comment: check your middleware maybe there is a redirection code

Comment: not solved yet checked all everything is fine

Comment: Try `php artisan serve`. I think it's more simple. Or as a better way, use VirtualHost (if you are using Apache).